# Data Catalog will not read technical metadata automatically from files in a bucket (GCS)

Tags: google-data-catalog

In Google Data Catalog I have tried to create a new entry group, then created a fileset entry where bucket and file pattern is configured. I have not defined a schema on purpose in the Fileset, as I want data catalog to automatically find the technical metadata within/from the files. Everything is set up via Google console UI.

Data Catalog does not find metadata related to the files in the bucket. However if I make a BigQuery table og a Pub/Sub topic, the metadata from these resources shows up immediately.

My hope was that Data Catalog will be able to scan the files in our buckets and show the metadata automatically (searchable). Files in the buckets are either .avro, .json, .parquet or .csv. As mentioned, this works for BigQuery and Pub/Sub. My understanding from the docs is that this should also work for objects in Cloud Storage.

Has anybody tried this and could please shed some light on this matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Data Catalog does not detect internal metadata about contents of GCS filesets at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I find quite strange that Google is not clear about this in their documentation. Can I ask you where you got this information? Is there any roadmap available for Data Catalog?

Comment: Data Catalog does not support that function. Which documentation page made you think this is not the case?

Answer (score 0):

On GCP platform, you can use Dataplex, where you need to create lake -> zone -> asset and asset type you can select as GCS bucket and attach that bucket to the asset.

Put data in GCS bucket in following manner /tablename/partition=1/filename.csv

Dataplex have discovery jobs which will fetch the metadata for you and publish it to DPMS or BigQuery or both.